# Increment the x axis by any number

Tags: pgfplots

I am new in tikz, I want to increment the x axis by any number(eg:2,3 e.t.c)

My current output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

I am using following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=8,
      ymin=0,ymax=8,xstep=1,ystep=1,
      xtick={-2,...,20},
      ytick={0,...,20},
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am used xstep=2 but the values not changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xstep` isn't defined by `pgfplots`, but I see it exists in TikZ, for modifying grids there. For your case you can just change `xtick={-2,...,20}` to `xtick={-2,0,...,20}`. Because the difference between -2 and 0 is 2, the numbers will be -2,0,2,4 and so on up to 20, instead of -2,-1,0,1 etc.

Though of course, since your axis stops at 8, you could just as well do `xtick={0,2,...,8}`.

Comment: T how I set length of x axis by 5cm

Comment: @Kevin `scale only axis,width=5cm`. See section 4.10.1
Common Scaling Options in the manual.

Comment: is it possible to remove or hide the y-axis values

Comment: @Kevin Can you please not ask a bunch of semi-(un)related questions in comments like this? I sort of answered that question already actually, in a comment to your other question (which I still do not understand): `yticklabels={}`.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T you are great.